# How to share Angular4 components to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

For historical reasons, we need to use Angular4 and AngularJS both in the same project. Is it possible to share Angular4 components to AngularJS? If yes, what's the best practice about that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert angular component into angularjs directive you can't share it is as component. Check this articles to convert component into a directive:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/upgrade-to-angular-components/
- https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives

Comment: Seems  like need to do some refactory and not easy, anyway, thanks!